# Bash if-statement gets stuck

Tags: bash, if-statement, sh

I get this loop but for some reason, the if conditional get stucks.
The while loop works perfectly.

The inputs are those (the x, y, z are word that changes everytime you execute the script):

```
name0="Car name X"

name1="Car name Y"

name2="Car name Z"
```

```
        echo $name0
        echo $name1
        echo $name2
while [ $ext -eq 0 ]
do
    if [ "$name1" = "$name2" ]
    then
    ext=1
        name1="`shuf -n 1 cars.csv | cut -d";" -f1`"
        name1c=`echo $name1 | cut -d" " -f1`
        ext=1
    else
        :
    fi
done
```

EDIT to loop:

```
while [ $ext -eq 0 ]
do
    if [ "$name1" != "$name2" ]
    then
        :
    else

        name1="`shuf -n 1 cars.csv | cut -d";" -f1`"
        name1c=`echo $name1 | cut -d" " -f1`
        ext=1
    fi
done
```

It outputs somethink like this (without #):

```
Car name 1

Car name 2

Car name 3
#
```

And gets stuck in the #, I can enter more text but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs in an infinite loop: since `name1` and `name2` are not equal in the beginning, you will not enter the `then` block of the if-then-else.  And thus, `exit` will never get the value 1.

On a side note: since `exit` is a shell builtin, you should rather prefer a different name for that variable to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok, changed to to the edit but still gets stuck.

Comment: Still an infinite loop that does not modify the `ext` variable.  Put echo statements in the then block and the else block to see it.

Comment: Alright, saw my big mistake. Tysm.
Just put another ext=1 after then block.